# Extra space in path when running VBA script on server

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

I hope I'm able to explain this correctly, but I have an Excel file that runs a VBA script for turning an Excel file/data into a .htm file for web publication.

On my own computer (Windows 10 Pro, Office 365) everything works as intended, but for some reason when I run the script on a different computer (specifically a remote server, running Windows 2016 Datacenter, Office 365) it adds a space in the filepath (behind "foldername") after executing/creating the htm file --> "C:\temp\foldername \filename.htm"
With the added space in the end of the filepath I'm unable to grab/open the file, due to Windows then giving the "directory name is invalid" error.

I tried searching Google/Stackoverflow, but I'm rather unsure on what keywords to use for finding an existing thread with the same issue.

If it helps, here is the code section of the VBA for creating the file:

```
Option Explicit

Private mstrAfasPublishPath As String

Public Function GetAfasPublishPath() As String

  Dim strPath As String

  If Len(mstrAfasPublishPath) = 0 Then
    strPath = Environ$("AfasPublishPath")
    If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
      strPath = "C:\Temp\"
    Else
      NormalizePath strPath
    End If
    CreateDirectory strPath
    mstrAfasPublishPath = strPath
  End If

  GetAfasPublishPath = mstrAfasPublishPath

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function GetAfasErrorResult(ByVal Err As ErrObject) As Variant

  GetAfasErrorResult = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)

End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub NormalizePath(strPath As String)

  Do While Right$(strPath, 1) = "\"
    strPath = Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)
  Loop

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CreateDirectory(strPath As String)

  Dim strParentPath As String

  If Len(Dir$(strPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

    strParentPath = Left$(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\"))

    If Len(strParentPath) <= 2 Then
      RaiseError "The drive or share of path '" + strPath + "' is not available."
    End If

    If Len(Dir$(strParentPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
      CreateDirectory strParentPath
    End If
    MkDir strPath

  End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub RaiseError(strMessage As String)

  Err.Raise vbObjectError, "AfasInternalFunctions", strMessage

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function PathCombine(strPath As String, strAppend As String)

  If Right$(strPath, 1) = "\" Then
    If Left$(strAppend, 1) = "\" Then
      PathCombine = strPath + Mid$(strAppend, 2)
    Else
      PathCombine = strPath + strAppend
    End If
  ElseIf Left$(strAppend, 1) = "\" Then
    PathCombine = strPath + strAppend
  Else
    PathCombine = strPath + "\" + strAppend
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Don't use `+` to concatenate strings! Always use the `&` like `strPath & "\" & strAppend`. The plus is for calculation only and can cause odd issues with strings. Every `+` in the code you show needs to be replaced with `&`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, unfortunately after I replaced all the + with & the problem remains

Comment: Try to go through the code step by step using F8 (on your server). Then check the values of the variable in each step and try to find out in wich line the additional space appears first. Then you can use the `Trim$()` function to get rid of an extra space in the end/beginning of a string at the determined line.

Comment: I've never used the F8 function before, it just highlights the lines yellow but doesn't showcase anything.

Comment: So good reason to learn how to debug your code yoursef: If you hold your mouse cursor over a variable you can see it's value. Also use the `View › Local-Window` to check the values of your variables. Check out [Debugging VBA Code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) for more info about debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I went through the code and checked the variables but none contained any space and showcased the way the should behave

Comment: I got it working! I will add the solution later, thanks!